# Rename files using a list

Tags: r

I am trying to rename a list of files and saving them into a new folder. There is a large number of files and I need to set up a new structure, where some files from one folder will be split in several folders and some files from different folders will be put in one. So, I want to create an Excel template including the OLD filename and the NEW filename in two columns. This looks like this:

| OLD | NEW |
| --- | --- |
| C:/R/TEST/Test000.xlsx | C:/R/TEST2/Test990.xlsx |
| C:/R/TEST/Test001.xlsx | C:/R/TEST2/Test991.xlsx |

I tried the following code:

```
filelist <- read.csv("test2.csv", sep = ";")

old_files <- filelist[,"OLD"]
new_files <- filelist[,"NEW"]

file.copy(from = old_files, to = new_files)
```

This however, returns the following error message:

> `Error in file.exists(from) : invalid 'file' argument`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `vectors` in your `file.copy` command instead of columns. You can use the following code:

```
library(readxl)
filelist <- read_excel("data.xlsx")

old_files <- filelist[["OLD"]]
new_files <- filelist[["NEW"]]
```

This looks like this:

```
[1] "C:/R/TEST/Test000.xlsx" "C:/R/TEST/Test001.xlsx"
[1] "C:/R/TEST2/Test990.xlsx" "C:/R/TEST2/Test991.xlsx"
```

Finally use this:

```
file.copy(from = old_files, to = new_files)
```